# PhoneGap can't use barcode-scanner-camera and Camera together in one application

Tags: android, cordova

In my PhoneGap application,  when the bar-code scanner window opened, then if I press Back button on the mobile phone, the camera is back and the website page in the application is also back. But the camera for photoes is well.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough to be answered. Please describe your problem more precise. PhoneGap supports 7 mobile platforms. Just for a start: On which platform is the problem occuring?